# Listbox item remain selected

Tags: zk

I have a bandbox with a Listbox inside.

My Listbox has "`onSelect`" listener, and inside this i do a `myListbox.clearSelection()`
after read the value of the selected item and write it on a TextBox.

The problem is, that when I open the bandpopup another time, the selected item in the List remain selected and Marked in blue color, and i can't select the same element twice because it's remain selected.

For example:

1. Open the Bandpopup.
2. Clik in a element, the value is written on the Textbox, and then learSelection()" is called.
3. The user clear the Textbox.
4. Reopen the Bandpopup.
5. Click on the same item in the ListBox.
6. Nothing occurs, because this element remains selected.

The Zul code:

```
<?page title="Enviar a" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<?variable-resolver class="org.zkoss.zkplus.spring.DelegatingVariableResolver"?>
<?init class="org.zkoss.zkplus.databind.AnnotateDataBinderInit" arg0="./envioWindow" ?>
<zk>
    <window title="Enviar a" border="normal" width="60%" id="envioWindow"
        apply="..............">
        <bandbox id="sectorReparticionBusquedaSADE" >
            <bandpopup apply="XXXXXX.FindSectorReparticionesBusquedaSADEBandboxComposer"
            id="sectorReparticionesComboBusquedaSADE" width="650px">
                <groupbox mold="3d">
                    <vbox>
                        <hbox>
                            <textbox id="textoSectorReparticionBusquedaSADE" />
                        </hbox>
                        <paging id="pagingSectorReparticionesDocsSADE" pageSize="10" />
                        <listbox mold="paging"
                        width="600px" id="sectoresReparticionesBusquedaSADEListbox"
                        model="@{listaSectorReparticionSADESeleccionada}"
                        selectedItem="@{sectorReparticionSeleccionada}"
                        paginal="${pagingSectorReparticionesDocsSADE}">
                            <listhead>
                                <listheader label="Código" width="30%" />
                                <listheader label="Nombre" height="70%" />
                            </listhead>
                            <listitem self="@{each=reparticion}">
                                <listcell label="@{reparticion.codigo}" />
                                <listcell label="@{reparticion.nombre}" />
                            </listitem>
                        </listbox>
                    </vbox>
                </groupbox>
            </bandpopup>
        </bandbox>
        <bandbox id="sectorBusquedaSADE" tooltiptext="Ingrese el nombre del sector correspondiente a la repartición seleccionada a la que desea agregar para enviarle un pase múltiple." >
            <bandpopup apply="ar.gob.gcaba.ee.satra.pl.consulta.FindSectorBusquedaSADEBandboxComposer" 
            id="sectorComboBusquedaSADE" width="650px">
                <groupbox mold="3d">
                    <vbox>
                        <hbox>
                            <textbox id="textoSectorBusquedaSADE" />
                        </hbox>
                        <paging id="pagingSectorDocsSADE" pageSize="10" />
                        <listbox mold="paging"
                        width="600px" id="sectoresBusquedaSADEListbox"
                        model="@{listaSectorSADESeleccionado}"
                        selectedItem="@{sectorSeleccionado}"
                        paginal="${pagingSectorDocsSADE}">
                            <listhead>
                                <listheader label="Código" width="30%" />
                                <listheader label="Nombre" height="70%" />
                            </listhead>
                            <listitem self="@{each=sector}">
                                <listcell label="@{sector.codigo}" />
                                <listcell label="@{sector.nombre}" />
                            </listitem>
                        </listbox>
                    </vbox>
                </groupbox>
            </bandpopup>
        </bandbox>
    </window>
</zk>
```

The listbox "sectoresReparticionesBusquedaSADEListbox" has the problem, the "sectoresBusquedaSADEListbox" don't have this problem, and for me both are equal.

Comment: Can you post a [ZK fiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/)?

Comment: No, is incredible, but only pass in one Listbox in my code. I can't reproduce in another listbox or in Zk fiddle.

Comment: upgrade your zk version to the one used in zk fiddle, or starts from your code, and remove anything not used to reproduce the problem then post that here or on a zk fiddle

Comment: Do you use a model to populate your listbox? In that case, try clearing the selection on the model, not the listbox.

Comment: Yes, I use a Model, ¿How i can do this? The model is a List<>

Comment: It would be easier to help if you gave us a **small** code/zul example. I tried it with a small example myself and the clearSelection works nicely.

Comment: Fragment of the Zul added.

Comment: Remove everything that is not necessary to reproduce that problem (style, groupboxes, paging, boxes, window, second listcolumn...). Furthermore, what version of zk are you using? The `@{}` binding was almost immediately deprecated after being introduced because it was buggy. And furthermore, where is the Composer with the listener?

Comment: Sorry, is a application that have passed through a lot of programmers and have a lot of unnecessary code, and different / strange implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this resetting the binder every time thath i open the BandPopup:

```
private void resetComponent() {
    this.binder = new AnnotateDataBinder(sectoresReparticionesBusquedaSADEListbox);
    this.binder.bindBean("sectorReparticionSeleccionada", this.sectorReparticionSeleccionada);
    this.binder.loadAll();
    this.listaSectorReparticionSeleccionada = new ArrayList<ReparticionBean>();
    this.binder.bindBean("listaSectorReparticionSADESeleccionada", this.listaSectorReparticionSeleccionada);
}
```